# Get specific row col values from mysql using vb 2012

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

I have one button retrieve I just want to get the database table "account" value by its row and col and display it in a textbox.  I keep on getting errors on the datafill line

```
 Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1
Dim dataset As DataSet
Dim datatable As DataTable
Dim sqlcon As MySqlConnection
Dim dataadapter As MySqlDataAdapter
Dim sqlcommand As MySqlCommand
Dim sql As String

Private Sub retrieve_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles retrieve.Click

    sqlcon = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Database=database;User ID=root;Password=;")

        sqlcon.Open()

    sql = "select * from account"
    dataadapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlcon)
    dataadapter.Fill(dataset)
    TextBox2.Text = dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: And what is the error message? (At a guess: `dataset` is null/Nothing. You need to create an object instance with `New`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the dataset that you pass to the Fill method.

```
....
dataset = new DataSet()
dataadapter.Fill(dataset)
...
```

Do not forget to close the connection when finished. It is a resource very costly to keep open when you not need it

```
Using sqlcon = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Database=database;User ID=root;Password=;")

    sqlcon.Open()
    sql = "select * from account"
    dataadapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlcon)
    dataset = new DataSet()
    dataadapter.Fill(dataset)
    TextBox2.Text = dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()
End Using
```

[See the Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)

However if you need only one row it is better to refine the query applying a WHERE clause to limit the results returned by the database.

```
    sql = "select * from account WHERE AccountName = @name"
    dataadapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlcon)
    dataadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWWithValue("@name", inputNameBox.Text)
    dataset = new DataSet()
    dataadapter.Fill(dataset, "Account")
    if dataset.Tables("Account").Rows.Count > 0 then 
        TextBox2.Text = dataset.Tables("Account").Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()
    End If
```

this hopefully will return just the row needed

Comment: ok let me try that first, is the textbox row item method ok? can i use the name of the of row or column instead of numbers. thanks

Comment: do you really need to retrieve the whole account table in order to get only a specific row's column value? You can use the column's name instead of index number for the item/column like : `dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("columnName")` or `dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0)("columnName")` or `dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0)!columnName`. But for the row, you need to specify which row by using [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) method or pre-filter your SQL query like `sql = "select * from account where yourRowId=someValue"`